# Batch renaming files from the commandline

Tags: command-line, batch-rename

I have files with the following names:

```
1_shahlirtsb_p.mp3_103899.mp3
2_shahlirtsb_p.mp3_103898.mp3
3_shahlirtsb_p.mp3_103897.mp3
4_shahlirtsb_p.mp3_103896.mp3
5_shahlirtsb_p.mp3_103895.mp3
6_shahlirtsb_p.mp3_103894.mp3
7_shahlirtsb_p.mp3_103893.mp3
```

How can I rename them from the command line (using regular expression) to `1_shahlir.mp3`, `2_shahlir.mp3`,and so on...

Comment: As steeldriver said, your question is off topic here. You could ask on [su] instead. However, the solution would be something like (this assumes no spaces in your filenames, just as shown) `for i in *mp3; do mv $i ${i/.mp3*/.mp3}; done`

Answer (score 2):

Try using the perl-based `rename` command e.g.

```
rename -n -v -- 's/tsb_p[.]mp3_\d+//' *.mp3
```

It will not actually rename your files until you remove the `-n` (no-operation) switch.

Comment: I encountered an error: sh.exe : rename : command not found. I use git bash on Win. What should I do?

Comment: @HamidehIraj if you are using git bash on Win, you can't expect answers on **askubuntu** to be relevant. I suggest you try a more appropriate StackExchange forum for your questions such as [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)